# List of images with Angular and Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am trying to make a list of images appear when clicked on a button. I have created image array, and they should repeat and show on the page. I don't know where is the error, here is my code.

```
 <body ng-app="StarterApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" >
  <md-content id="content"flex>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <p>{{content}}</p>       
    <img ng-src="{{image}}"/>
      <div ng-repeat="pic in pics">
      <img src="{{pic}}"/>
      </div>          
 </md-content>
</body>
```

App.js

```
var app=angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', '$mdSidenav',function($scope,$mdSidenav)    {
    $scope.openGallery=function(){
    $scope.title="Our work so far";
    $scope.content="";
    $scope.image="";     
    $scope.pictures=pics;
    var pics=[
    {
        url: "svg/camera.png";
    },{
        url: "svg/email.png";
    },{
        url: "svg/person.png";
    }
    ]};
```

Comment: check the answerr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller -

```
var pics=[
        {
            url: "svg/camera.png";
        },{
            url: "svg/email.png";
        },{
            url: "svg/person.png";
        }
    $scope.pictures=pics;
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="pic in pictures">
  <img src="{{pic.url}}"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Code still doesn't work, it messes up entire page. Page loads when I delete the array, but then I have no images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<md-grid-list>` and `<md-grid-tile>` it is defined in angular material. Using this you can create simple gallery view for images. Use `$mdDialog` for showing selected image.

[Grid List](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList)

[$mdDialog](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog)